# How to concatenate all the array elements except the first one, using Bash?

Tags: bash

```
InputList="Item1,Item2,Item3,....,ItemN"
```

Desired output:

```
NewList1="Item1"

NewList2="Item2;Item3;....;ItemN"
```

Note that the separator of the original input list is a , (comma) whereas that of the new lists is a ; (semicolon).

Please suggest a suitable Bash script. Thanks.

Comment: Note that generally, requests for someone to write a program for you are often not well-accepted here. Showing your own attempt and a specific problem you encountered is more likely to result in helpful answers.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
InputArray="Item1,Item2,Item3,....,ItemN"

List1="${InputArray%%,*}"

List2="${InputArray#*,}"
List2="${List2//,/;}"

echo "$List1"
echo "$List2"
```

Output:

```
Item1
Item2;Item3;....;ItemN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays and `IFS`.

```sh
InputList='Item1,Item2,Item3,....,ItemN'
IFS=, InputArray=($InputList)
NewList1="${InputArray[0]}"
NewList2="$(IFS=\;; printf '%s' "${InputArray[*]:1}")"
```